# Sorting html table based on input field

Tags: php, html-table

I need to sort the table based on the input field. I want to avoid reloading the table data, that's why I only want to sort the table. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<div class=buyer_list>
    <div class='ui-grid grid-buyer_list'>
        <div class="buyer_opt" >
            <span>Search By:</span>
            <?php echo '
            <input type="text" method="POST" id="searchdata" name="searchdata">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" name="buyer_btnsearch" type="text" onclick="return search_onlookup()" style="display: inline;"> Search</button>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class=buyer_list>
            <div class='ui-grid grid-buyer_list'>
                <div class='ui-rowheader'></div>
                <div class="ui-rowlist">
                <?php while($rs1=mysql_fetch_array($result1)):?>
                    <div class="ui-rowdata" onclick="clckrow(this);"> 
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D buyercode'><?php echo $rs1['buyercode'];?></div>
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D unitcode'><?php echo $rs1['unitcode'];?></div>
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D buyername'><?php echo $rs1['buyername'];?></div>
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D tcp'><?php echo $rs1['TCP'];?></div>
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D tcppaid'><?php echo $rs1['TCPPaid'];?></div>
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D tcpperc'><?php echo $rs1['TCPpercPaid'];?></div>
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D bal'><?php echo $rs1['balance'];?></div>
                        <div class='ui-coldata col D print'>NO</div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;?>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You want to sort or you want to filter searched data...?

Comment: just sort the data shown on the table using an input field.

Comment: How you sort data based on the input field? I'm asking about the workflow.

Comment: all the data will be displayed on the table and when the user searched on the search bar, the searched data will append on the top of the table without removing any other data or reloading the table.

Comment: You have to use jquery for this... One more thing, you can hide the unmatched row. It won't delete data just hide it.

Comment: I am preventing the unmatched data to be hidden, do you have any reference that i can look? i am a newbie. i searched google but seems i can't find one. thanks a lot.

Comment: You want to search all columns or any specific one. Like `buyercode`,`buyername` etc

Comment: Yes, and move the row to the top of the table